# Excel search string for value and return INDEX MATCH

Tags: excel, formula

I am trying to search within a string of text and find a value from a range. With that value, i'd like to return the adjacent SKU. I currently have my columns broken down as so
A. SKU
G. Keyword
N. Incoming
O. Incoming SKU

The goal is to place a formula in Cells O2:O which will search the adjacent cell in N2:N for a value found in range G2:G. Once the value is found in G2:G, id like it to return the SKU found in A2:A.

Normally i would use an index/offset/match with wildcards to do this, but this is the reverse of what i would normally do.

Any help?

In this picture, i labled the red columns as the SKUs i want to return, Green is the String and keywords i am searching through, and blue is the output column i'd like the code for.
[image]

Thank you

Comment: How do you know you want to return `STD 100011`  for `1950 II`, instead of `STD 100012`?

Comment: That is going to be a lot of array formulas,  It will drastically slow down the calc times and may even crash Excel.  I assume there are more rows than just the 30 you have shown.

Comment: I don't. I figured it would be too difficult to have a formula determine the difference between the two. This tool would be used to take incoming purchase orders and quickly identify the last price we bid on an item. We generally bid the same price across the board for 2900 Gen 2 regardless of however we inventory them, and this goes the same for the rest of the units we buy. Since we do that, i used the keywords to group each SKU with the rest of the base units. Once i have this formula/column down, i can continue to build the rest of the vba to record the historical data.

Comment: @Scott Craner Yes, the sheets will vary from 30 items to lists of up to (if not over) 1000 units. There's no simple formula to do this? I am rather new to functions, would it be possible to do a blend of VBA and formulas?

Comment: pure vba would be better, using memory arrays instead of constantly referring to the worksheet.

Comment: @Scott Craner Thank you. I am going to do some research and attempt this from a VBA standpoint. I wouldnt mind any help going down this route as it would drastically cut down processing time on bid lists.

Comment: =/ really seems like the last 3 questions i've asked have gone unanswered. It's not that they're unable to be answered, they're just never responded to by any of the help.